# What is the right way for removing timers in React. When they are created after onClick function is executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I apologize for my not so good english. Since I'm new to React development I need some help.

let say, that I have some onClick event and in my onClick function I set setTimeout or setInterval. I wish to clear the timers after the function is finish.

In React official docs we can make use of componentWillUnmount for removing timers from setTimeout or setInterval. But in my code I dont remove any of my components so componentWillUnmount is not call.

Shoud I use componentDidUpdate to check if the state or props is change and then clear the timers, or there is a better way.

What is the best way to remove the timers.

Thank's for the help :)

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        index: 0
    }

    timer = null;

    next = () => {
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
           this.setState((prevState) => ({index: prevState.index + 1}));
        }, 1500);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        if(this.state.index !== prevState.index){
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
         <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" onClick={this.next}></i>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on your usage of the timer. React docs specify it this way because the timers in components cannot update anything once component unmounts. If you need to clear it before, just feel free to do so

Comment: Just wanted to point out that since you only ever save one timer reference at a time that you may as well just clear the timeout right before setting it again (in `next`), thus making the componentDidUpdate check unnecessary.  This will actually also fix a possible bug where you inadvertently clear the timeout you just set because you are clearing it based upon the index changing. I.E. you save the timer id, update state, CDU checks the index updated and clears the timer before it expired.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of clearing the timeouts in a `componentWillUnmount` method is to "clean up" so the timeouts don't do anything. If you clear the timeouts at the end of the `onClick` handler, those timeouts will *never* do anything, since you've cleared them before they ran.

You only really need to clear a timeout if you *don't* want that code to run.

So it really comes down to the question: under what conditions do you want to clear the timeouts? It seems like you may want to clear the timeout on `componentWillUnmount`, because if you don't they will call `this.setState`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In my case I need to call this.setState in my onClick handler. If I understand your answer and the answer from Edgar Chávez. When the callback is executed the timer stops and is no longer active. So even if I dont clear the timer in my case will be okay. And I can remove this.timer from the code. I ask this becouse I know that every time we use setTimeout or setInterval we have to clean the timer. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to clear a timer that is no longer active. When using setTimeout, the timer stops after the callback is executed. The only reason to clear the timer would be to prevent its execution, as James mentioned. Your code should work without the componentDidUpdate part. Also, allow me to point out that your next() function should be updating the index property in the state, not the timer property.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And yes you are right it should be the index property in the state, my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use a controller variable to check update, something like this :

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        intervalId : 0,
    currentCount:0
    }
}

doIt = () => {
var intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
   // store intervalId in the state so it can be accessed later:
   this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
}

timer = () => {
var newCount = 0;//use this controller
    newCount = newCount + 1;
  this.setState({ currentCount: this.state.currentCount + newCount });
   if(newCount >= 1) { 
   clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
   } 
}

  render() {
    return <div>Timer =  {this.state.currentCount} <p onClick={this.doIt}>clcik on me</p></div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

i hope this code help
https://jsfiddle.net/40q18ygp/